# Where do the jQuery libraries reside?

Tags: jquery

The articles I have found on the basics of jQuery have all kinds of reasons why you should use jQuery, but I'm not finding a clear answer on where the libraries reside. Are they in the browser? Are they on the server? Are they distributed? The best I seem to find is a partial answer that some of the libraries can be called from Google and other sources.

Comment: you can include the file in your project or call it from the server on google

Comment: jQuery is a library based on JavaScript. While JavaScript comes with your browser, jQuery does not.

Comment: Maybe you could explain, which article? We are not mindreaders, unfortunately  ;-) Maybe times in a local /js folder, but could be a CDN...

Comment: @Rogier, There were quite a few articles that came up in various searches for jQuery basics and similar terms. I could go back and copy all the addresses into the question, but that doesn't seem to be a legitimate use of Stack Overflow. However, I made the comment to illustrate that this information, which seems basic to me, seems to be commonly missing from articles about jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are regular JavaScript files and are embedded using a `<script>` tag, either from your own server or from their CDN.

Answer (score 0):

The library is the file you download from jQuery. The file exists on your server (or a server) and then it is downloaded to the browser when the page is loaded. So, here's a google-hosted version of jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you copy and paste that into the `<head>` tag of your page, it will load the jQuery library up for use.

Comment: Better to place it before the closing `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This weekend I asked this question of some programmers at the Big Sky Dev Con. One of them explained that the JQuery libraries start in the web server and are sent to the browser, like a CSS file is sent to the browser, as called for in . He said that the JQuery libraries are not built into browsers.

This answer is similar to others, but the explanation was clearer for me.